# Button onserverclient not working for Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, button, server, webforms

I have a button that is created in Runtime,

```
sb.Append("<button runat="server" onserverclick="btnTaskDelete_Click"  id='Task1' style="float: right; margin-right: 14px;height: 27px;width: 27px;" class='btn btn-danger'><i style ="transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 12px; height: 6px; display: block;" class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>");
```

Then Append this StringBuilder(sb) to Literal.

And for Server Method

```
protected void btnTaskDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

But whatever i tried, btnTaskDelete_Click is not fired!!!

**Note**
I solved it by calling Onclick Method in client side then ajax call to call serverside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add HTML button server control from code-behind by using `StringBuilder` like that. Use [`HtmlButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class to create the button and put that inside a form (or other server control like `Panel`) by following this example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var button = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton();

        button.Id = "Task1";
        button.Attributes["style"] = "float: right; margin-right: 14px;height: 27px;width: 27px;";
        button.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-danger";
        button.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnTaskDelete_Click);
        button.InnerHtml = "<i style ="transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 12px; height: 6px; display: block;" class="fa fa-trash"></i>";

        Form1.Controls.Add(button); // add to form server control named 'Form1'
    }
}
```

The `StringBuilder` way to create HTML elements only apply if all created elements are literal HTML elements, not a server control (marked with `runat="server"` attribute).

**Update:**

If you want to put the button inside a `div` control, simply set the element as server control like `<div id="ParentDiv" runat="server"></div>` and put it as insertion target:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var button = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton();

        button.Id = "Task1";
        button.Attributes["style"] = "float: right; margin-right: 14px;height: 27px;width: 27px;";
        button.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-danger";
        button.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnTaskDelete_Click);
        button.InnerHtml = "<i style ="transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 12px; height: 6px; display: block;" class="fa fa-trash"></i>";

        ParentDiv.Controls.Add(button); // add to form server control named 'Form1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add dynamic button like as a string. As you know, there are other feature to achieve this same functionality as like below.

Style:

```
.myclass
{
        float: right; margin-right: 14px;height: 27px;width: 27px;
}
```

Dynamic control:

```
Button myControl = new Button();
myControl.Text = "Click Me";  
myControl.ID = "Task1";
myControl.CssClass = "btn btn-danger myclass";
myControl.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
Page.Controls.Add(myControl);

void button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     //your stuff goes here...
}
```

**Note:** This should be in page load to initial control in each postback. This will maintain viewstate so it will take care about entered value in controls.